# Why is upgrading from an LTS to LTS more safe than doing upgrades from the Short Term Supports?

Tags: upgrade

How is an LTS to LTS upgrade different than a Standard Release to Standard Release upgrade? Are fresh installs usually preferred to guarantee a stable environment?

Comment: Can you edit your answer and delete all the stuff on the chat-ban. I mean it really is not relevant to your otherwise valid question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any upgrade is a risk. Things can break in between. Power failure can be an issue. So purely based logics going from LTS to LTS is less risky than going LTS->NON-LTS->NON-LTS->NON-LTS->LTS.

The whole idea of using an LTS *is* to not upgrade in between LTSs. You get a lot of stability in exchange for not getting the latest software out-of-the-box.

And yes; if possible I would always go for a reinstall. A reinstall has a side-effect: it will remove all packages you installed and that you never used.

Answer (score 0):

Because short term supports contain many broken packages and removing or adding them may cause serious complication in package dependencies.
A user like me who likes to try things and always install packages from less reliable sources tend to get a lot lot of broken packages or even break good packages over time.
So it is always recommended to upgrade between LTSs