# System failed to boot after upgradng EOL Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: 13.10, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

Today I upgraded my EOL (end of life) system Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04. It downloaded 738 MB. Then while upgrading or installing, it messaged something like this: "finishing the installation (& stopping to install further) as many errors are detected. Press 'ENTER' to continue"
I pressed 'ENTER' key. Then immediately the '$' (prompt) returned back. I confirmed that the system was upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04. Then the system failed to reboot. I checked before rebooting that 'print screen' button wasn't functioning. Also while upgrading, I read at one point it was written that there is high possibility that the system would be broken.

As the system failed to reboot, I installed back my previous distribution Ubuntu 13.10 using bootable pen drive.

Please look below to know what all I did to upgrade:

> First I edited the /etc/apt/sources.lst file by replacing
>   archive.ubuntu.com with old-releases.ubuntu.com
>
> Then I ran:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade (this command didn't do anything; simply had output "0 upgraded, 0 installed ..........")
> sudo do-release-upgrade
> ```

Then it downloaded 738 MB of data but the system couldn't boot after the upgradation. Having no other option, I reinstalled the previous distro Ubuntu 13.10.

I feel the only solution left for me is to download the iso image of the new distro & install preparing bootable pen drive.

Also, I can not experiment upgrading many times as it will increase my monetary expense as each upgradation requires 738 MB of data to download.

Is it O.K. or any other way also!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I feel the only solution left for me is to download the iso image of the new distro & install preparing bootable pen drive.**

This is the appropriate solution regarding 13.10. Remember; 13.10 was not a LTS; In many respects, it should be considered a test platform, preparing the way to the next lts. If you have however 12.04; Upgrading this to 14.04 is officially supported, and should upgrade without consequence. If a consequence arises, then a bug report is greatly appreciated.

From my own experience; it is always preferable to do fresh installs, particularly on machines that have seen a lot of use and customization.

Comment: Oh really! Other than LTS releases should be considered as test platforms, preparing way for next LTS!! Yes seems so. Thanks. Do you mean that upgrading from LTS to LTS is officially supported? That's a good news. It's a really helpful answer.

Comment: I checked your profile & saw [this Q](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449589/why-is-upgrading-from-an-lts-to-lts-more-safe-than-doing-upgrades-from-the-short) you asked regarding upgrading between releases (LTS & non-LTS). Great informations!

Comment: That is very kind of you to say. Yes; I was surprised to hear about it too, but since looking into it; I have known people who have upgraded every lts from 6.04 without having to reinstall. Is there anything you still feel is unanswered? If not, would you be so kind to accept this answer so the question can be resolved? It helps keep the stack exchange clean.